# What is causing INFO replication and UNSUBSRIBE events in Redis

Tags: redis

When running redis-cli monitor I'm seeing the following events over and over. What is causing these events? And can they be suppressed?

Windows Redis version 2.8.2400

```
1503693326.380836 [0 127.0.0.1:21771] "UNSUBSCRIBE" " \xcc\xf0(\xe4\x00\x01B\x83l\x8a\xc0\xaa\x80\xd2)"
1503693326.662796 [0 127.0.0.1:19523] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\xd2\xbc\x95Tw\xa2KE\x9e\x80:\xd1'YM\x91"
1503693326.662823 [0 127.0.0.1:19522] "INFO" "replication"
1503693327.366005 [0 127.0.0.1:20967] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "9\xecQ+\xd7\xc0\xcfD\x96\xe0E9\xacP\xf06"
1503693327.366032 [0 127.0.0.1:18375] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\xb7\xaem\xc0h\x1a`H\x82\xea\xc6\xa6\xa8\x97a&"
1503693327.647036 [0 127.0.0.1:20284] "INFO" "replication"
1503693327.647090 [0 127.0.0.1:20285] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\xa3O\xfd\x8a\x8e;?E\x91].\xc6\xb9\xbbc3"
1503693329.429580 [0 127.0.0.1:22990] "UNSUBSCRIBE" " \xde\x94 <\xaa\x16J\x91z4\xf5\x8a\xe5.2"
1503693329.429606 [0 127.0.0.1:22989] "INFO" "replication"
1503693330.380803 [0 127.0.0.1:19747] "INFO" "replication"
1503693330.380878 [0 127.0.0.1:19748] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "piZ\xcf\x8b|II\x98M/\x00\xdaxvR"
1503693330.740826 [0 127.0.0.1:19706] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\x80\xb7v\xf8#\xb7\x0cD\x9bm\xb1\x9c\xb6f\xc8\xd7"
1503693330.740855 [0 127.0.0.1:19705] "INFO" "replication"
1503693332.412236 [0 127.0.0.1:19385] "INFO" "replication"
1503693332.412292 [0 127.0.0.1:19386] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\xba\xf7&\xa2\x8c\x13\xadN\xbeV\b\xe9\x9a\x1e\x95\xc6"
1503693332.662329 [0 127.0.0.1:19267] "INFO" "replication"
1503693332.662396 [0 127.0.0.1:19268] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "r\x06\xb0\xaf\xfa\xd7\x8cO\xab\xf8\b/\x1bB+\xd6"
1503693333.006409 [0 127.0.0.1:18250] "INFO" "replication"
1503693333.006462 [0 127.0.0.1:18251] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "\x13\xac(\xb0\xe6s\x9fF\x8d\xf7\x8b\x89\x96\x03\xdd\xa7"
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing these events?

One or more clients are sending these commands. Your version of Redis is too old to be really helpful in identifying the "offending" clients - I suggest you upgrade to the latest official version (i.e. not the Windows version)

> And can they be suppressed?

The [`MONITOR`](https://redis.io/command/monitor) command dumps everything. You can postprocess the output if you want to filter things.

Note that monitoring a production instance is potentially dangerous as can affect the server's performance.